# How to show all processes of an AVD in attach dialog of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

According to the [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug),

> If you're using an emulator or a rooted device, you can check Show all processes to see all processes.

However, After I have checked on the 'Show all processes", I cannot see any system processes other than my own app even if I have met both of the conditions: It's an AVD and it's rooted by script from https://github.com/newbit1/rootAVD.

Any ideas? I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox Patch 4, and the AVD is running API 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one knows the answer, I'm gonna answer it myself. Set property

> ro.debuggable

of /default.prop to 1, done.